# extract JSON variables with php for email use

Tags: php, json

I'm having difficulty extracting JSON values (obtained by using a URL) into email variables.  The following code works (I have removed identifiable and usable data).

```
$addr = "https://98905:Twmdf56sn0cb@geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/insights/".$ipaddr;
// fetching geoip data in JSON format
$json = (file_get_contents($addr)); 
//parsing JSON format to object format
$obj = json_decode($json); 
// assigning values to separate variables for email message
$var_country = $obj->country->names->en;
$var_city = $obj->city->names->en;
$var_city_confidence = $obj->city->confidence->en;
$var_city_geoname_id = $obj->city->geoname_id->en;
$var_location = $obj->location->accuracy_radius->en;enter code here
```

However one set of data is an array that looks like this (identifiable and usable data scrubbed):

```
"subdivisions":[{"geoname_id":5166838,"iso_code":"NY","confidence":24,"names":{"ja":"ニューヨーク州","fr":"New  York","ru":"Нью-Йорк","en":"New York","zh-CN":"纽约州","de":"New York","pt-BR":"Nova Iorque","es":"Nueva York"}}]
```

My difficulty lies in extracting the "names" "en" part from the subdivisions  multi-array.  All the previous arrays are single units, this multi and I'm having difficulty drilling down to the "names" "en" part from subdivisions and getting that value into an array using the same process as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$p=json_decode('{"subdivisions":[{"geoname_id":5166838,"iso_code":"NY","confidence":24,"names":{"ja":"ニューヨーク州","fr":"New  York","ru":"Нью-Йорк","en":"New York","zh-CN":"纽约州","de":"New York","pt-BR":"Nova Iorque","es":"Nueva York"}}]}');

$enNames = array();

foreach($p->subdivisions as $subdivision){
    $enNames[]=$subdivision->names->en;
}

print_r($enNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get the `en` key, you can do something like this:

`$objects->subdivisions[0]->names->en;`

If you are wanting retrieve each set of data, loop through them like so:

```
foreach($objects->subdivisions[0]->names as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' --- ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

and modify to your needs.

Comment: Okay, great! the solution above works perfectly. I'm talking about this one:$objects->subdivisions[0]->names->en; For my own edification and education, can someone explain the brackets with the zero and the purpose of that? Thanks.

Comment: Represents the item with index 0 in the subdivisions array, in other words, the first subdivision. In my answer, I suggest a loop thru the subdivisions array in case you have more than 1 subdivision.